# Make model function to stop counting

Tags: django, function, datetime, model

In a django app i have a model function that counting the progress of an event between date time fields. Is it possible to stop the progress after reaching 100. For example:

models.py

```
start_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
end_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

model function

```
def get_progress(self):
  if (self.status) == 'New' or (self.status) == 'Finished':
    now = timezone.now()
    progress = ((timezone.now() - self.start_appointment) / ((self.end_appointment - now) + (now - self.start_appointment)))*100
      if progress > 100.0:
         ...
      return progress
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the Python `min()` function. That will return your progress calculation or 100 if the progress calculation is larger.

```
def get_progress(self):
  if (self.status) == 'New' or (self.status) == 'Finished':
    now = timezone.now()
    progress = min(((timezone.now() - self.start_appointment) / ((self.end_appointment - now) + (now - self.start_appointment)))*100, 100)
      return progress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_progress(self):
  return ((timezone.now() - self.start_appointment) / ((self.end_appointment - now) + (now - self.start_appointment)))*100

def other_process():
  while self.get_progress() < 100:
    Do stuff here...
  return progress
```

This will return the progress once it the appointment is over. Maybe you will want to return True or something instead to assert the appointment is complete